# firebase auth => auth/captcha-check-failed and "Hostname match not found" errror

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting the following message when trying to use `auth.linkWithPhoneNumber()`. All other auth services on the same domain are working fine.

> auth/captcha-check-failed and "Hostname match not found" errror

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/394

Now I know this issue is reference all over but the solutions are not working for me... The solution i keep finding is to update `Authorized Domains` however there are 2 reasons that might not be the solution for this app.

1. All other auth services are working just fine
2. I am unable to change anything under Authorized Domains.

***Login by phone DOES work on localhost, but not in prod***

When updating Authorized domain the changes do not save. instead i get the following

> Error updating authorized domain list

### Question

If the solution for the `auth/captcha...` is to update domains then why cant i save changes there? If that is likely not the solution then do you know what it could be

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @omar

Comment: Experiencing the exact same problem. How did you solved it ?

Comment: You need to add the domain including the subdomain

Answer (score 6):

I added my domain in the Authorised domain
like if my domain is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) i added example.com
but it's not working
so i try Adding with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and it worked for me.
Add [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) instead of example.com

Answer (score 2):

What's your browser and do you have any Allow CORS extension installed? Try to toggle it to off and try again.

Comment: this worked for me. By disabling the CORS extension, problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

go to your firebase settings and find Authorized domains
there are some default domains you should add your frontend domain there then your application will work fine