# Firebase Google sign error: This domain is not authorized to run this operation

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I just deploy my react app to firebase , after deployment I am having trouble getting the Firebase Google sign-in to work and got the error :"This domain (*********.web.app) is not authorized to run this operation. Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab."
see the error in below pic:
[See This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVpWr.png)

also I've whitelist the domain and add it to authentication tab
[See This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBgNX.png)

,but don't know why I still got the error. Can Anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Try answer below and let me know if this was helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72529545/17539341

Answer (score 0):

This problem is likely due to the sign-in methods that are enabled. In the firebase console, you need to enable the Google sign-in method

[image]
[image]

Comment: i enabled the google sign-in method but still getting the error. why?

Comment: That is rather strange. I'm not that certain. I personally use vanilla js and haven't really run into this problem. Sorry!! Hope someone has a good solution for you!!

Comment: yup i know but i can't understand what to do. It's third day i'm still stuck on this problem .